# Add Lambda Authorizer Output to the Input of other Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

## Background

I currently have an authorizer that takes a JWT token and decodes it and checks if valid or not to build a policy document, then that is used to grant or deny access to API endpoints.

Currently, the endpoints are using query strings as parameters to grab data.

## Problem

I need to make it so that the values for the user and email etc are the ones that come from the decodes JWT Token. How do I pass the decodes values to the input of the other lambda functions?

I am open to suggestions, or links, or at least a point in the right direction.

Comment: you need to call lambda from another lambda?

Comment: @DerekMenénedez no, API Gateway calls one Lambda function (the authorizer) and then uses the response from that function to determine if the caller is authorized to call the actual Lambda function (or other backend) that the endpoint is configured with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-lambda-authorizer-output.html), you need to include those in the `context` section of the authorizer response. Then you will need to map the context values in your API Gateway mapping template.

If you are using Lambda Proxy Integration then the context returned from the Authorizer function will be in the `event.requestContext.authorizer`. That does not appear to be documented anywhere, but I always recommend printing the entire event object to your logs when you first start working on a Lambda function so you can see exactly what is being passed into it.

Comment: Thanks for the first step I've actually read that documentation before just hard to understand the steps to take.  I do currently log my event object to CloudWatch so that I am able to look at it. Would I just have to add a property to the event object before the authorizer is done executing. IE Do something like event["userEmail"] = "johnSmith@email.com"?

Comment: No, as I stated you would add it to the `context` section of the authorizer response. API Gateway will add that to the `event` object later. You add it to the `context` section of the IAM policy that the authorizer returns.

Comment: @MarkB - 
It is documented here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-lambda-authorizer-output.html.  But, not sure if the doc is done after your comment :-)